# What CTE would generate listed results or is there a better way to aggregate the names in the tables provided

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

Is there a CTE that can be written to query these tables and to generate the listed results? If so what would it look like?

This is SQL Serve 2012 SP2.

```
create table d ( id int, calldate date)

insert into d 
values (3, '2016-08-03'), (4, '2016-08-04'), (5, '2016-08-05'),  
       (6, '2016-08-06'), (7, '2016-08-07'), (8, '2016-08-08'),
       (9, '2016-08-09'), (10, '2016-08-10'), (11, '2016-08-11'),    
       (12, '2016-08-12'), (13, '2016-08-13'), (14, '2016-08-14'),    
       (15, '2016-08-15'), (16, '2016-08-16'), (17, '2016-08-17'),    
       (18, '2016-08-18'), (19 , '2016-08-19' ),    (20 , '2016-08-20' ),    (21 , '2016-08-21' ),    (22 , '2016-08-22' ),    (23 , '2016-08-23' ),    (24 , '2016-08-24' ),    (25 , '2016-08-25' ),    (26 , '2016-08-26' ),    (27 , '2016-08-27' ),    (28 , '2016-08-28' ),    (29 , '2016-08-29' ),    (30 , '2016-08-30');

create table w ( id int, startdate date, enddate date, holiday varchar(60))

insert into w 
values (1, '2016-05-02', '2016-05-08', ''),        
       (2, '2016-05-09', '2016-05-15', 'Company holiday'),        
       (3, '2016-05-16', '2016-05-22', 'Company holiday'),        
       (4, '2016-05-23', '2016-05-29', ''),        
       (5, '2016-05-30', '2016-06-05', ''),        (6, '2016-06-06', '2016-06-12', 'Company holiday'),        (7, '2016-06-13', '2016-06-19', ''),        (8, '2016-06-20', '2016-06-26', ''),        (9, '2016-06-27', '2016-07-03', ''),        (10, '2016-07-04', '2016-07-10',  'Company holiday'),        (11, '2016-07-11', '2016-07-17', ''),        (12, '2016-07-18', '2016-07-24', ''),        (13, '2016-07-25', '2016-07-31', ''),        (14, '2016-08-01', '2016-08-07', ''),        (15, '2016-08-08', '2016-08-14', ''),        (16, '2016-08-15', '2016-08-21', ''),        (17, '2016-08-22', '2016-08-28', ''),        (18, '2016-08-29', '2016-09-04', ''),        (19, '2016-09-05', '2016-09-11', '')

create table e (id int, name varchar(100), init varchar(10), IsAManager bit)
insert into e values    (2  , 'Alice' , 'AA', 0),    (8  , 'Jack ' , 'JM', 1),    (9  , 'Ace  ' , 'AQ', 0),    (10 , 'Mike ' , 'MM', 0),    (16 , 'George' ,'GH', 0),    (21 , 'Jenny' , 'JL', 1),    (22 , 'Bill ' , 'BG', 1),    (30 , 'Blank' , '  ', 0)    

CREATE TABLE r ( id   INT,  NAME VARCHAR(50) );
INSERT INTO r     VALUES          (13, 'Primary'), (22, 'Secondary'), (33, 'Prim Trd'), (44, 'Sec Trd'); 

create table ca (e_id int, r_id int, d_id int, s_id int)
insert into ca values         (8   ,13  ,8   ,13),     (8   ,13  ,9   ,13),      (8   ,13  ,10  ,13),      (8   ,13  ,11  ,13),      (8   ,13  ,12  ,13),      (8   ,13  ,13  ,13),      (8   ,13  ,14  ,13),      (10  ,13  ,15  ,13),      (10  ,13  ,16  ,13),      (10  ,13  ,17  ,13),      (10  ,13  ,18  ,13),      (10  ,13  ,19  ,13),  
(10  ,13  ,20  ,13),      (10  ,13  ,21  ,13),      (16  ,13  ,22  ,13),      (16  ,13  ,23  ,13),      (16  ,13  ,24  ,13),      (16  ,13  ,25  ,13),      (16  ,13  ,26  ,13),       (16  ,13  ,27  ,13),      (16  ,13  ,28  ,13),      (10  ,22  ,8   ,13),      (10  ,22  ,9   ,13),      (10  ,22  ,10  ,13),  
(10  ,22  ,11  ,13),      (10  ,22  ,12  ,13),      (10  ,22  ,13  ,13),      (10  ,22  ,14  ,13),      (16  ,22  ,15  ,13),      (16  ,22  ,16  ,13),       (16  ,22  ,17  ,13),      (16  ,22  ,18  ,13),      (16  ,22  ,19  ,13),       (16  ,22  ,20  ,13),      (16  ,22  ,21  ,13),      (2   ,22  ,22  ,13),  
(2   ,22  ,23  ,13),       (2   ,22  ,24  ,13),      (2   ,22  ,25  ,13),      (2   ,22  ,26  ,13),       (2   ,22  ,27  ,13),      (2   ,22  ,28  ,13),      (30  ,33  ,8   ,13),      (30  ,33  ,9   ,13),      (30  ,33  ,10  ,13),      (30  ,33  ,11  ,13),      (30  ,33  ,12  ,13),      (30  ,33  ,13  ,13),  
(30  ,33  ,14  ,13),      (30  ,33  ,15  ,13),      (21  ,33  ,16  ,13),       (22  ,33  ,17  ,13),      (30  ,33  ,18  ,13),      (30  ,33  ,19  ,13),       (30  ,33  ,20  ,13),      (30  ,33  ,21  ,13),      (2   ,33  ,22  ,13),      (30  ,33  ,23  ,13),       (30  ,33  ,24  ,13),      (30  ,33  ,25  ,13),  
(30  ,33  ,26  ,13),       (30  ,33  ,27  ,13),      (30  ,33  ,28  ,13),      (30  ,44  ,8   ,13),      (30  ,44  ,9   ,13),      (30  ,44  ,10  ,13),      (30  ,44  ,11  ,13),      (30  ,44  ,12  ,13),      (30  ,44  ,13  ,13),      (30  ,44  ,14  ,13),      (30  ,44  ,15  ,13),      (30  ,44  ,16  ,13),  
(30  ,44  ,17  ,13),      (30  ,44  ,18  ,13),      (30  ,44  ,19  ,13),      (30  ,44  ,20  ,13),      (30  ,44  ,21  ,13),      (2   ,44  ,22  ,13),      (2   ,44  ,23  ,13),      (21  ,44  ,24  ,13),      (21  ,44  ,25  ,13),      (21  ,44  ,26  ,13),      (30  ,44  ,27  ,13),      (30  ,44  ,28  ,13)


CREATE TABLE s       ( id        INT, specialty VARCHAR(50)    ); 
insert into s values     (13 , 'Pediatric')  ,     (28 , 'EMT'),       (55 , 'ER'),     (62 , 'ICU'),    (74 , 'GIU'),    (88 , 'BBB')
```

Table W

```
║ id │ startdate  │  enddate   ║  
╠════╪════════════╪════════════╣    
║ 11 │ 2016-07-11 │ 2016-07-17 ║  
║ 12 │ 2016-07-18 │ 2016-07-24 ║  
║ 13 │ 2016-07-25 │ 2016-07-31 ║  
║ 14 │ 2016-08-01 │ 2016-08-07 ║  
║ 15 │ 2016-08-08 │ 2016-08-14 ║  
║ 16 │ 2016-08-15 │ 2016-08-21 ║  
║ 17 │ 2016-08-22 │ 2016-08-28 ║  
║ 18 │ 2016-08-29 │ 2016-09-04 ║  
║ 19 │ 2016-09-05 │ 2016-09-11 ║
```

Table D

```
║ id │ calldate   ║  
╠════╪════════════╣  
║ 3  │ 2016-08-03 ║  
║ 4  │ 2016-08-04 ║  
║ 5  │ 2016-08-05 ║  
║ 6  │ 2016-08-06 ║  
║ 7  │ 2016-08-07 ║  
║ 8  │ 2016-08-08 ║  
║ 9  │ 2016-08-09 ║  
║ 10 │ 2016-08-10 ║  
║ 11 │ 2016-08-11 ║  
║ 12 │ 2016-08-12 ║  
║ 13 │ 2016-08-13 ║  
║ 14 │ 2016-08-14 ║  
║ 15 │ 2016-08-15 ║  
║ 16 │ 2016-08-16 ║  
║ 17 │ 2016-08-17 ║  
║ 18 │ 2016-08-18 ║  
║ 19 │ 2016-08-19 ║  
║ 20 │ 2016-08-20 ║  
║ 21 │ 2016-08-21 ║  
║ 22 │ 2016-08-22 ║  
║ 23 │ 2016-08-23 ║  
║ 24 │ 2016-08-24 ║  
║ 25 │ 2016-08-25 ║  
║ 26 │ 2016-08-26 ║  
║ 27 │ 2016-08-27 ║  
║ 28 │ 2016-08-28 ║  
║ 29 │ 2016-08-29 ║  
║ 30 │ 2016-08-30 ║
```

Table E

```
╔════╤════════╤═════════╤════════════╗  
║ id │ name   │ initial │ IsAManager ║  
╠════╪════════╪═════════╪════════════╣  
║ 2  │ Alice  │ AA      │    0       ║  
║ 8  │ Jack   │ JM      │    1       ║  
║ 9  │ Ace    │ AQ      │    0       ║  
║ 10 │ Mike   │ MM      │    0       ║  
║ 16 │ George │ GH      │    0       ║  
║ 21 │ Jenny  │ JL      │    1       ║  
║ 22 │ Bill   │ BG      │    1       ║  
║ 30 │ Blank  │         │    0       ║  
╚════╧════════╧═════════╧════════════╝
```

Table R

```
╔════╤═══════════╗  
║ id │ name      ║  
╠════╪═══════════╣  
║ 13 │ Primary   ║  
║ 22 │ Secondary ║  
║ 33 │ Prim Trd  ║  
║ 44 │ Sec Trd   ║  
╚════╧═══════════╝
```

Table S

```
|ID | Specialty |  
|---+-----------|  
|13 | Pediatric |  
|28 | EMT       |  
|55 | ER        |  
|62 | ICU       |  
|74 | GIU       |  
|88 | BBB       |
```

Here is the linking table that links these tables together.
Table CA

```
║ e_id │ r_id │ d_id │ s_id ║  
╠══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╣  
║ 8    │ 13   │ 8    │ 13   ║  
║ 8    │ 13   │ 9    │ 13   ║  
║ 8    │ 13   │ 10   │ 13   ║  
║ 8    │ 13   │ 11   │ 13   ║  
║ 8    │ 13   │ 12   │ 13   ║  
║ 8    │ 13   │ 13   │ 13   ║  
║ 8    │ 13   │ 14   │ 13   ║  
║ 10   │ 13   │ 15   │ 13   ║  
║ 10   │ 13   │ 16   │ 13   ║  
║ 10   │ 13   │ 17   │ 13   ║  
║ 10   │ 13   │ 18   │ 13   ║  
║ 10   │ 13   │ 19   │ 13   ║  
║ 10   │ 13   │ 20   │ 13   ║  
║ 10   │ 13   │ 21   │ 13   ║  
║ 16   │ 13   │ 22   │ 13   ║  
║ 16   │ 13   │ 23   │ 13   ║  
║ 16   │ 13   │ 24   │ 13   ║  
║ 16   │ 13   │ 25   │ 13   ║  
║ 16   │ 13   │ 26   │ 13   ║   
║ 16   │ 13   │ 27   │ 13   ║  
║ 16   │ 13   │ 28   │ 13   ║  
║ 10   │ 22   │ 8    │ 13   ║  
║ 10   │ 22   │ 9    │ 13   ║  
║ 10   │ 22   │ 10   │ 13   ║  
║ 10   │ 22   │ 11   │ 13   ║  
║ 10   │ 22   │ 12   │ 13   ║  
║ 10   │ 22   │ 13   │ 13   ║  
║ 10   │ 22   │ 14   │ 13   ║  
║ 16   │ 22   │ 15   │ 13   ║  
║ 16   │ 22   │ 16   │ 13   ║   
║ 16   │ 22   │ 17   │ 13   ║  
║ 16   │ 22   │ 18   │ 13   ║  
║ 16   │ 22   │ 19   │ 13   ║   
║ 16   │ 22   │ 20   │ 13   ║  
║ 16   │ 22   │ 21   │ 13   ║  
║ 2    │ 22   │ 22   │ 13   ║  
║ 2    │ 22   │ 23   │ 13   ║   
║ 2    │ 22   │ 24   │ 13   ║  
║ 2    │ 22   │ 25   │ 13   ║  
║ 2    │ 22   │ 26   │ 13   ║   
║ 2    │ 22   │ 27   │ 13   ║  
║ 2    │ 22   │ 28   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 33   │ 8    │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 33   │ 9    │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 33   │ 10   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 33   │ 11   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 33   │ 12   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 33   │ 13   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 33   │ 14   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 33   │ 15   │ 13   ║  
║ 21   │ 33   │ 16   │ 13   ║   
║ 22   │ 33   │ 17   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 33   │ 18   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 33   │ 19   │ 13   ║   
║ 30   │ 33   │ 20   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 33   │ 21   │ 13   ║  
║ 2    │ 33   │ 22   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 33   │ 23   │ 13   ║   
║ 30   │ 33   │ 24   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 33   │ 25   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 33   │ 26   │ 13   ║   
║ 30   │ 33   │ 27   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 33   │ 28   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 44   │ 8    │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 44   │ 9    │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 44   │ 10   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 44   │ 11   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 44   │ 12   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 44   │ 13   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 44   │ 14   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 44   │ 15   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 44   │ 16   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 44   │ 17   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 44   │ 18   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 44   │ 19   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 44   │ 20   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 44   │ 21   │ 13   ║  
║ 2    │ 44   │ 22   │ 13   ║  
║ 2    │ 44   │ 23   │ 13   ║  
║ 21   │ 44   │ 24   │ 13   ║  
║ 21   │ 44   │ 25   │ 13   ║  
║ 21   │ 44   │ 26   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 44   │ 27   │ 13   ║  
║ 30   │ 44   │ 28   │ 13   ║
```

Note: The e.id is the id of the last person who performed the trade either "Prim Trd" or "Sec Trd" for that week with disregard to id 30 blank. But if no trades happened for that week then e.id= 30 blank. Where initials are a list of initials that did a trade for that week. Same for names

**Desired Result Set:**

```
║ startdate       │ enddate      │ holiday │ specialty   │ initials    │  rolename   │ s.id │ e.id   │ name         │   WasThisTraded   ║  
║ 2016-08-08      │ 2016-08-14   │         │ Pediatric   │ JM          │  Primary    │ 13   │ 8      │ Jack         │   N               ║  
║ 2016-08-08      │ 2016-08-14   │         │ Pediatric   │ MM          │  Secondary  │ 13   │ 10     │ Mike         │   N               ║  
║ 2016-08-08      │ 2016-08-14   │         │ Pediatric   │             │  Prim Trd   │ 13   │ 30     │ Blank        │   N               ║  
║ 2016-08-08      │ 2016-08-14   │         │ Pediatric   │             │  Sec Trd    │ 13   │ 30     │ Blank        │   N               ║  
║ 2016-08-15      │ 2016-08-21   │         │ Pediatric   │ MM          │  Primary    │ 13   │ 10     │ Mike         │   Y               ║  
║ 2016-08-15      │ 2016-08-21   │         │ Pediatric   │ GH          │  Secondary  │ 13   │ 16     │ George       │   N               ║  
║ 2016-08-15      │ 2016-08-21   │         │ Pediatric   │ JL, BG      │  Prim Trd   │ 13   │ 22     │ Jenny, Bill  │   N               ║  
║ 2016-08-15      │ 2016-08-21   │         │ Pediatric   │ JL          │  Sec Trd    │ 13   │ 30     │ Jenny        │   N               ║  
║ 2016-08-22      │ 2016-08-28   │         │ Pediatric   │ GH          │  Primary    │ 13   │ 16     │ George       │   Y               ║  
║ 2016-08-22      │ 2016-08-28   │         │ Pediatric   │ AA          │  Secondary  │ 13   │ 2      │ Alice        │   Y               ║  
║ 2016-08-22      │ 2016-08-28   │         │ Pediatric   │ AA          │  Prim Trd   │ 13   │ 2      │ Alice        │   N               ║  
║ 2016-08-22      │ 2016-08-28   │         │ Pediatric   │ AA, JL      │  Sec Trd    │ 13   │ 21     │ Alice, Jenny │   N               ║
```

Comment: You have provided verbose detail and having the create table statements is very good, it has an error though on table "ca" and "e" and cannot be executed. It would be much better if you provide a shorter sample data.

Comment: There is no "SQL Server 2012 R2" - just "2012" - corrected

Comment: @marc_s Just searched for "sql server 2012 r2" and found [this link](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/04/sql-performance/next-ver-announcement). Took me a second to figure out...

Comment: What is the specific question? How to aggregate names or how to find _most relevant_ sale if there are many within one week? Most of work to do looks pretty straightforward.

Comment: Questions to you: 1) How would `IsAManager` look like if several persons are in a row? same about `WasThisTraded`. 2) `specialty` - if sales in different specialties happened. 3) What does this logically mean that some person has 7 rows for a week with same `r_id` and `s_id`? He sells every day same thing on `primary` basis and only once?

Comment: Answers: 1) Took out IsAManager, its not needed 2) yes different ones happen, the ex is keeping dataset small 3) we just list their initial once in the results

Comment: What have you tried? What part is troublesome? We can help you with your code, but you don't appear to have any.

Comment: I have a problem visualizing this being done by a CTE. I don't see the data as being hierarchical. I can solve it with udf functions but its too slow.

Comment: @CiberLover007 add your source into the question, we'll assist if possible.

Comment: While providing the relevant tables ddls and dmls for sample data have earned your question my upvote, you might want to consider starting your next question with a verbal description of the logic needed to get the desired results. I'm currently logged in on a low resolution device and can't even find the question.

Comment: What is W table - how it should be connected with others? Can you say anything about logic? How it should work? I've read your question few times, prepare tables and still don't know how to start helping you.

Comment: The W table was just a table to use that designates the beginning of the week and ending of the weeks. Should I delete this and re-open the question again but with my source code?